# Image import not working in react js app.js file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to import image in my app.js file i used two methods:

method 1: 
import logo from './images/arrow/' --> here image file name not coming

method 2:
 `<img src={require("./images/arrow/")} />` here also image file not coming

How to solve this error.

[image: image name given]
[image: image not working]

Comment: filename with its type is not appearing i mean image file is not detecting

Comment: Could you explain more on why you have to import an image? You can usually just give the relative path of the image in the src (or other) attribute.

Comment: relative path or import anyway but the image is not found thats the problem

Answer (score 1):

images should live in the `public` folder in a react app or a subfolder

so `arrow.jpg` should live in something like `public/images/arrow.jpg`

you don't need to import it into your component you simply use it like so:

`<img src={'/images/arrow.jpg'} alt="arrow-text" />`

React knows to look inside the public/subdirectory for images like this

Comment: The problem here is image is not found the path i mentioned is correct but the image is missing

Comment: what do you mean the image is missing though?

Comment: edited with image sample see the image path and see the import, while importing image not found.

Comment: because `arrow` is a directory and not a file. it needs to be a file with an extension like `arrow.svg` or `arrow.png` etc

Comment: or do `arrow/nameoftheimage.png` (or whatever the file type is)

Comment: Even if i give the name its not working see my edited question

Comment: can you show where you gave it a name and what the name is including file extension?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215288/discussion-between-sabrilogesh-k-and-red-baron).

Comment: webdeveloper.png is the file name

Comment: or do `src={logo}`

Comment: @SabrilogeshK did you leave the room?

Comment: wow spent way too much time on this. moving my image to public solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

Only js files don't need the `.js` at end of file, you should add `.jpg`/`.png` ... to your either first or second try

Comment: there is no image file detecting, thats what i have posted with the suggestions toolbar

Comment: If for example your `image.png` lives inside `arrow` folder, the path is `./images/arrow/image.png`